# pasar datos entre actividades

Tags: android

Hola estoy tratando de enviar estos datos entre actividades pero no me funciona que puede ser?

```
  entrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            String usu=usuario.getText().toString();

          //  intent.putExtra("turno", turno.getItemAtPosition(turno.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
            intent.putExtra("usuario", usu);



            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }

    });
```

y con esto lo recibo en la segunda actividad

```
  String usu = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

---

android:id="@+id/usuarios" este es el edittext que quiero que envie y lo recibe "@+id/usuario"  y ya los tengo declarados ambos

Comment: falta obtener la referencia del EditText, como se define en el layout, que id tiene definido? agrega el Layout que carga MenuActivity y tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: android:id="@+id/usuarios" este es el edittext que quiero que envie y lo recibe "@+id/usuario"  y ya los tengo declarados ambos

Comment: como se llama el layout donde se encuentra : android:id="@+id/usuarios" y que Activity lo carga (revisa setContentView() ); recuerda que actualizaciones de información es preferible lo realices en tu pregunta para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores.

Comment: android:id="@+id/usuarios" es del MenuActivity y el que lo carga es MainActivity

Comment: Ok ya lo solucione lo que pasa esque no lo estaba recibiendo el el Oncreate si no en otra parte gracias